# Webservice needs to be accessible through website

Tags: .net, php, vb.net, web-services, web

I have a .exe program which has an embedded webservice running on port 800.
I can access it locally via 127.0.0.1:800 just fine once the program is executed.

I need to be able to send the service commands such as: *** 127.0.0.1:800/dev *** will get a list of devices attached to the program.

To my knowledge i need to forward port 800 on my router and then access my internet IP externally and I should be able to view/access this web service? am i correct?

I am then wanting to create a PHP site which will send the desired commands back to the web-service running on my home pc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, port forward to your machines local IP address on port 800 should be all you need to do. Be aware though of the associated risks of opening ports up to public access. You may want to restrict (if you can on your router) access from only certain known IP addresses.